# How to implement a centralized event system? Android - LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, architecture, android-livedata

So I came up with what I call a centralized event system for simple `Snackbar` notifications or errors displaying a `DialogFragment`. The way I do this is I have all my activities extend from a `BaseActivity` and in such class I create a `CompanionObject`. This companion object hosts two MutableLiveData objects, one for Success notifications and one for Error notifications.

This `BaseActivity` on the `OnCreate` method observes these two LiveData objects and it displays Snackbars or DialogFragments when needed. It works, but I've been told that it's bad practice and not so well architecture-wise...

Why is this wrong? I don't fully comprehend why it is considered bad practice. This way you can call BaseActivity.successNotification.postValue(event) and that's it!

```
open class BaseActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object {
        val successNotification = MutableLiveData()
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        successNotification.observe(...)
    }
}
```

Comment: https://dev.to/antonholmberg/the-baseclass-anti-pattern-16il

Comment: Wow, it makes so much sense. Thanks for sharing!